# Develop headline to show supplementary information

Tags: header-line

How can I easy make a function that display information in headline of buffer?

I mean that first line of buffer wouldn't be used for displaying file content and instead would be used for showing necessary information.

Like in `info` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs has support for a header line which works pretty much like the mode line, but at the top of the buffer. See variable `header-line-format`, which can be configured in the same way as `mode-line-format`.

This variable defaults to nil (no header), but you could define a function to set it to display whatever you want. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html) for more.